# Any way to obtain FileDescriptor with Mono(.net)?

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, file-descriptor

Probably, this is a complicated question, but I would try to shoot.

I use Monodroid(Mono for Android),and try to implement media stream to UDP socket.

[Best way to stream audio and video from an Android phone to a RTMP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165154/best-way-to-stream-audio-and-video-from-an-android-phone-to-a-rtmp-server)

This is a useful pointer for me as a result to take advantage of 
[FileDescriptor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileDescriptor.html)

However, basically, FileDescriptor is a UNIX oriented concept, and Mono(.net) is Windows oriented conept, it appears the [UDPClient class of .net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not support to obtain FileDescriptor for the instance.

Is there any way to obtain FileDescriptor with Mono(.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Android doesn't natively support UDP streaming: [Network Protocols](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#network), so yes you should look for RTMP server option and no you probably can't use `UdpClient`.

The code in the answer to [Best way to stream audio and video from an Android phone to a RTMP server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10509481/620138) is fairly easy to convert to C#. [`LocalServerSocket`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Net.LocalServerSocket), [`LocalSocket`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Net.LocalSocket) and [`LocalSocketAddress`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Net.LocalSocketAddress) are in the [`Android.Net`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=N:Android.Net) namespace and so is [`FileDescriptor`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Java.IO.FileDescriptor) in [`Java.IO`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=N:Java.IO).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Aaron, I am going through your answer and my code, and come back to report soon.

Comment: after all, I switched my Android Project to Java base, and relating your comment, I opened a new Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072763/a-localsocket-unix-domain-client-server-data-flow-issue-for-mediarecorder-in-a